# Why does imported wallet not show correct balance?

Tags: mnemonic-seed, mymonero, balance, cakewallet, wallet

I have imported my seed from CakeWallet to MyMonero on iPhone, but MyMonero wallet balance shows 0 XMR.

What is the problem?

Comment: Have you fully synced the blockchain?

Comment: To properly import a non MyMonero seed into a MyMonero wallet, you have to pay an import fee of 0.1 XMR. Most convenient option is probably to create a new MyMonero wallet and subsequently send the funds from Cake Wallet to your newly created MyMonero wallet.

Answer (score 0):

Don't import it, just create an entirely new wallet on MyMonero and just send all your coins from CakeWallet to MyMonero. This gives you the following benefit:

- You won't have to rescan the entire blockchain from where your old wallet started and just start scanning today. Saving ALOT of time.

Don't import just send the entire thing over.

But if you want to keep your old transaction history for whatever reason, you'll have to pay that import fee.